# How to validate range of a nullable property in c#?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, model, range

I have a model in which some properties are nullable. And they have a range attribute also. But the modelstate is not checking the range attribute validation.

Here is my property:

```
    [Range(0, 9223372036854775807L)]
    public long? OfferId { get; set; }
```

Comment: `long` is not nullable.  `long?` is nullable.  Also `[MaybeNull]` is not a model validation attribute, it's a code analysis attribute.

Comment: inside `set` you can control the range... the setter is there for that porpouse

Comment: @MarcoBeninca IME [Range] attribute is  a much better place to check than the setter, for view models. Infact, I now exclusvely use `{get;init;}` for view models, so I KNOW it can't change after it's been validated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you expect your offer_id (it's not a good naming convention in c# btw - properties should be pascal case e.g. OfferId) then the type should be *long?*. Also if the property is nullable then the Range annotation will only be checked if it's not null. To sum up all you have to do is:

```
[Range(0, 9223372036854775807L)]
public long? OfferId { get; set; }
```

10 will pass 
-10 will fail 
null will pass

If you would like the null to not pass you can also add the [Required] annotation next to Range one.

Comment: I tried this but still -10 is passing without any validation error.

Comment: Are you checking ModelState in the controller's action? Code of the view (if it's MVC) and controller would be useful.

Comment: Yes I am checking "ModelState.IsValid" inside my api controller.

Comment: I am looking for this feature to implement a web api with same route/uri, but more than 10 different combinations parameters body json. In which some parameters are null in some case but required in another case.